# How do I remove the tap effect when scrolling over <ons-list-item>'s but keeping the effect when tapping?

Tags: onsen-ui

When I scroll through my `<ons-list>`, the `<ons-list-items>` get highlighted with a darker grey background color, I would like such effect to show up only when tapping on a list item, I don't want the effect when scrolling through the list.

Is there any way to get rid of the highlight effect when scrolling through?

Answer (score 0):

WebKit Mobile is the choice renderer used by mobile devices. One rarely used style property is -webkit-tap-highlight-color, which allows developers to change the default tap highlight color. Here's how to use it!

```
    /* light blue at 80% opacity */
    html {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(201, 224, 253, 0.8);
         }

    /* change it for a div that has a similar background-color to the light blue tap color */
   .blueDiv {
      -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(251, 185, 250, 0.9);
            }
```

Changing the -webkit-tap-highlight-color property value is the key! Also note that using RGBA color allows the extra dimension opacity for the highlight so that the color isn't so harsh.

http://davidwalsh.name/mobile-highlight-color

But in onsenUi for change or remove tap effect just change this css class:

```
 .list__item_active:active {
   background-color: #d9d9d9;
   -webkit-transition: none;
   -moz-transition: none;
   -o-transition: none;
    transition: none;
   }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for that! What I really want is to deactivate the effect only when scrolling, I was wondering if there was an option or I need to get my hands dirty with javascript.